# What's the best way of closing a modal after a request finishes?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

**Context:** I want to create a modal which lets the user fill in a form, and submit it. The modal should close after the POST request finishes. There are multiple modals with similar behavior but different form content, so I need to make it reusable. The data in the form is not used anywhere else in the frontend app, and is only stored in the backend.

**Relevant tech stack:** react, redux, react-redux, redux-saga, no SSR

**Option 1: Store modal & request state in redux**

Opening and submitting the modal would trigger the following sequence of events:

1. Dispatch action to open modal
2. Dispatch action to submit form with data
3. Send POST request to submit form, set redux loading state to true
4. If success, set redux loading state to false, and "modal open" state to false

**Concerns:** Conceptually places a lot of functionality in redux, when that functionality is, in principle, specific to the modal itself.

**Option 2: Store the request state in redux, but store modal state in the component, use useEffect to check when the request succeeds**

Opening and submitting the modal would trigger the following sequence of events:

1. Open the modal, which changes some local "modalOpen" state to true
2. Dispatch action to submit form with data
3. Send POST request to submit form, set redux loading state to true
4. If success, set redux loading state to false
5. In the modal component, a useEffect hook or componentDidUpdate function checks if the state changed from e.g. `{loading: true, success: false}` to `{loading: false, success: true}`, and if so, set the local modalOpen state to false

**Concerns:** brittle, error prone, strong coupling between useEffect hook and redux state and how the state transitions from one into another.

**Option 3: Submit the request in the component, don't use redux at all.**

Opening and submitting the modal would trigger the following sequence of events:

1. Open the modal, which changes some local "modalOpen" state to true
2. Call fetch and submit the post request
3. In the .then() callback, check if the request succeeds. If it does, set the modalOpen state to false

**Concerns:** looks like an anti-pattern, because I'm calling fetch in the component itself.

**What would your recommended approach be, and why?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with Option 3 Because It's the simplest and most straightforward way to go about it. The React Documentation Has an [example](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html#example-using-ajax-results-to-set-local-state) of making an API call from within the a component so I don't think its an anti-pattern. 
Your concern in option 1, is perfectly valid. Modal state should be localised to the Modal and not to the Global state stored in Redux. Option 2 is similar to option 1

Answer (score 1):

Option 3 should be good per your context. It's okay to use fetch in the component itself since you only need it there. Only use redux or any global state management if you have data that is used across multiple components in your app.

Answer (score 0):

I would choose **option 1** if your application if sufficiently large since fetching data from store may appear in many pages. In this way, you can reuse the modal. 


However, if the application is not very large, I may probably use **option 3** because as @seyi_adel said, it may be more convenient and straight forward.